# Can I know the difference between these alerts?And also need some tips about attr?

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="abc">
    <span data-rel="hai">Hello</span>
    <span data-rel="bye">Bye</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click','.abc >span',function(){
        alert(($(this).attr('data-rel')));                  // This Code alerts hai.
        alert($('.'+($(this).attr('data-rel'))+'_cls'));    // I thought this code would alert as .hai_cls but it alerts as [object object].
});
```

Can I know the difference between these?

Comment: Why would it alert the same thing? In one you alert the value of the `rel` data attribute, in one you alert the value of a jQuery CSS class selector lookup. Both with an unnecessary pair of parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(    $('.'+($(this).attr('data-rel'))+'_cls')    );
```

It call the object because the $('.'+   in front

```
alert(      $(this).attr('data-rel')+'_cls'        );
```

It call just the object name like you want

Answer (score 1):

The first one alerts the attr value which is "hai"
The second one alerts the object with class "hai_cls"